# Distinct In SQL Query resulting duplicate Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

In my database there is multiple entries from same employee so I would like to get the Latest entry by way of identifying the auto number field.  But using below sql code with distinct in eno is resulting duplicate entries.

```
SELECT distinct(eNo), auto_num from mc_employee 
order by auto_num
```

Any clues about what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Post your sample data and expected output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DISTINCT` is not function applied on *specific* fields of the `SELECT` clause. It is rather applied to *all* the fields present in the `SELECT` clause.

If you want to get the latest record then you can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT eNo, auto_num
FROM (
   SELECT eNo, auto_num,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY eNo ORDER BY auto_num DESC) AS rn 
   from mc_employee ) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY auto_num
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy solution which works nicely :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below query:

```
SELECT eNo,auto_num 
FROM
( SELECT eNo, auto_num, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY eNo ORDER BY auto_num DESC) as RN
  FROM mc_employee
)T
WHERE RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is `TOP(1) WITH TIES ... ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()`

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES eNo, auto_num
FROM mc_employee
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY eNo ORDER BY auto_num DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an sub-select solution also:

```
SELECT distinct(dist.eNo), (select max(auto_num) from mc_employee i where i.eNo=dist.eNo) auto_num
from mc_employee dist
order by auto_num
```